# Why use Get at all?

Tags: http, post, get

I see many discussions arround the topic, but seen to always post's method get a better place...

> "Get is  a insecure method" (for some propurses)

is little bit faster and smaller than post, but for real is arround in top max 9 kb difference and even in great projects i don't see the problem nowadays.

Get can't handle as much data than Post, so for big request's you will use post.

I know the patterns, i know how to use Get and Post and etc, i still use it, but the real question is why?

Why use this?

Comment: Because they have vastly different semantics. You use POST if you want to send something to a server, and you use GET if you want to retrieve something.

Comment: *"Get is a insecure method"* – [citation needed] [tag:fud]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET and POST are literally just different verbs. There's no fundamental difference between a GET and a POST request on a technical level. Most POST requests contain additional data in the body that GET requests don't; but that's mostly because of the primary difference between them: **they mean different things**. You don't need to send body data in a GET request because you're *requesting data*, not sending any.

So this leaves the primary difference, again: they're different verbs that mean different things and are treated differently by clients and servers. GET requests are for requesting information from a server, and can be highly cached, which is a primary reason HTTP is very scalable. POST requests send data to the server and request the data to be processed; that should not and is not cached and is treated differently in everything from the client through middleware to the server.

There's no "better" or "more secure", you simply use different verbs for different semantics.

Comment: So the meaning is the relevant part afterall.

I'm okay with that, i just wanna to know if have some tech level difference, this question is closed i think.